# restarting node throws already exists error

Tags: cassandra, datastax

I have restarted one of the cassandra nodes in 6 node cluster after changing few things in c*.yaml file but the service didn't start and when checked in log. it shows node with address already exists. And says to use cassandra.replace_address option. Can anyone kindly tell me why its showing already exists error for the same node and possible solutions for this.

Many thanks.

Comment: Did you change your data directory? Please post the exact error message.

Comment: Yes, I changed the data directory. pls find the error below:

    java.lang.RuntimeException: A node with address /1.*.*.225 already exists, cancelling join. Use cassandra.replace_address if you want to replace this node.

Comment: That's why. It is not finding the system tables etc so it thinks it needs to bootstrap, but the other nodes already have the address in peers so it thinks its a replace node scenario.

Comment: Is there live data in the cluster? Why did you change the data directory?

Comment: there is no live data, its initial setup. I have copied the yaml from other node and updated all the address except new locations and started the server. So I made those changes in yaml and restarted. Any possible solution for this?

Comment: If there's no data just clear out each of your data and commitlog directories on each node and restart them all.